# Workshopping many needs into one solution?

Tags: workshop

**Background**

One of our user groups has seven different needs. Our stakeholders want *some* solution that solves all of these needs in one solution. The needs vary a bit and are not all directly related.

**The problem**

I tried running an ideation workshop where I went through the needs and background for each, but there were too many user needs for the participants to keep track of once the ideation step started. It's hard to take seven different needs into account when thinking of ideas...

**The question**

Is there a good way to structure a big workshop where you have multiple user needs, and the point is to find *one* solution for them all? Since the needs cannot be grouped into one bigger need (they are all a bit different), I feel like I can't reduce the number of needs.

Comment: I would question whether there are indeed seven unique needs, or whether one or more needs come from similar underlying problems. Generally for a given goal or problem, there is a primary driver behind it, especially when you are talking about one user group. I would like to understand the actual needs a bit more, because the best way to solve a problem well is to be able to simplify it, and you are starting with a complex one.

Comment: Good point, Michael. In this case, I did manage to simplify the needs into about three more general needs. However, I've encountered similar issues in the past and wanted to hear you guys' ideas on how to approach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should workshop this, but it's not going to be quick. You might need several days to several weeks to properly conduct discovery for seven separate customer needs.

I'd approach workshopping a solution for each individual need, vs. artificially forcing each need to work in the same solution with the other needs. You might discover as a group that one or more of the needs doesn't really fit with the others, and would be best approached in a different way. A good, rigorous discovery session will get all that out on the table.

If you need a good framework, and time is short, you might take a look at Jake Knapp's *[Sprint](https://www.thesprintbook.com/the-design-sprint)* book and website.

Comment: in the same line of your comment, he may discover overlaps, but I agree 100%, each problem should be treated individually